# What is the earliest article in which Leibniz used 'matrices'?

Tags: geometry, abstract-algebra, linear-algebra

The Chinese were using matrices ( *fengcheng* in the *Nine Chapters of the Mathematical Art*), long before they were used in Europe which suggests that possibly they were introduced by way of them. For example, Leibniz was well known as a sinophile. What's the earliest article he wrote using matrices or *fengcheng* (the latter is sometimes translated as rectangular array).

Comment: A manuscript from June 1678, a paper from May 1684, see [Knobloch, Leibniz’s Theory of Elimination and Determinants](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-4-431-54273-5_17). For speculations about the Chinese origin see [Hart, The Chinese Roots of Linear Algebra](https://www.amazon.com/Chinese-Roots-Linear-Algebra/dp/0801897556).

Comment: @Conifold: That should probably be an answer.